How do you organize a seach bar with different options?
How do i structure a search that should include a search bar, two categories (all objects, and only digitised objects) and four search rooms(objects, people, institutions and articles)?
i have this option:

and this one (sorry it is the same words but in german

is there another way to display that toggle button and structure it so the search rooms are clear?
thank you so much for your help!

It's a search bar with filters.
A viable option is the combination of tabs with a drop-down menu within the search field:

Codepen

thank you! that looks good. i looked at it too many years from the same perspective. it is really better to switch the categories around and have "all" and "digitised" as tabs on top. many thanks!!!
